# Jasper report export to pdf gives exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte

Tags: java, spring-boot, jasper-reports

I have been looking into this for hours but I didn't find any helpful resources

I am trying to export Jasper reports as pdf inside spring boot app, but I get an exception (shown in the end of the question)

I am not very sure but [I found a link](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/535644/noclassdeffounderror-comlowagietextpdffontmap) that states that the exporter is using old version of itext dependency (which was called com.lowagie.text; new ones are com.itextpdf.text as per the link) but still it didn't mention how to solve this issue

My code is this:

```
public void getRpt2(HttpServletResponse response) throws JRException, IOException, SQLException {

    System.out.println("get resource!!! ...");
    InputStream appCreatedReportStream
      = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/jasperReports/App_created_en.jrxml");
    System.out.println("Start compiling!!! ...");
    JasperReport jasperReport
      = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(appCreatedReportStream);

    // should save the report to avoid long compile time
    JRSaver.saveObject(jasperReport, "App_created_en.jasper");

    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();

    System.out.println("fill report!!! ...");

    Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
              jasperReport, parameters, connection );

    // export to pdf

    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(
      new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("app_created_report.pdf"));

    SimplePdfReportConfiguration reportConfig
      = new SimplePdfReportConfiguration();
    reportConfig.setSizePageToContent(true);
    reportConfig.setForceLineBreakPolicy(false);

    SimplePdfExporterConfiguration exportConfig
      = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
    exportConfig.setMetadataAuthor("ANB");
    exportConfig.setEncrypted(true);
    exportConfig.setAllowedPermissionsHint("PRINTING");

    System.out.println("set config!!! ...");
    exporter.setConfiguration(reportConfig);
    System.out.println("export config!!! ...");
    exporter.setConfiguration(exportConfig);
    System.out.println("exportReport!!! ...");
    exporter.exportReport();
}
```

My gradle dependencies are :

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports
compile group: 'net.sf.jasperreports', name: 'jasperreports', version: '6.6.0'
```

Note:

I added this dependency to try to solve the issue but it didn't work, supposedly it have the missing class

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf
compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.0.6'
```

The exception that I get is this one, it happens in the last line of the method shown above:

```
"org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfContentByte
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at com.ejada.staripo.security.JwtTokenFilter.doFilter(JwtTokenFilter.java:58)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfContentByte
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.PdfGlyphRenderer.determinePatchedItext(PdfGlyphRenderer.java:59)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.PdfGlyphRenderer.<clinit>(PdfGlyphRenderer.java:52)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.initExport(JRPdfExporter.java:585)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:544)
    at com.ejada.staripo.controller.ReportsController.getRpt2(ReportsController.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    ... 79 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 95 common frames omitted
```

**Important notice for the duplicate question claim:**

I understand what is meant by `ClassNotFoundException` but I am asking why I am getting it in the jasper reports (since I am installing the dependency with Gradle which shall automatically get all needed dependencies & classes) so I am asking about this particular case which is not referenced in the claimed duplicate questions referenced

Answer (score 1):

You can use code as follows:

```
    // setting report parameters
    HashMap parameters = new HashMap();

    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/jasperReports/App_created_en.jrxml");
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream);
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

    // Pass compiled report to print
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReportMain, parameters,  new JREmptyDataSource());
    JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint);
    jasperViewer.setVisible(true);
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "app_created_report.pdf");
```

Otherwise try lower version of itext:

```
com.lowagie itext   2.1.7.js6
```

Comment: How this can solve a *NoClassDefFoundError* problem?

Comment: If we use above code then it is not using JRPdfExporter which having dependency of that class.

Comment: Also you can use given version of itext which will resolve your problem: com.lowagie itext 2.1.7.js6